# Oracle apex authentication schemes login errors

Tags: oracle-apex, sql-pl

```
FUNCTION authenticate(p_username IN VARCHAR2,p_password IN VARCHAR2) RETURN 
BOOLEAN 
is
l_count integer;
begin
select count(*)
into   l_count
from   STUDENT, ADMIN, ORGANISATION
WHERE upper(Student.STUDENT_ID, ADMIN.ADMIN_ID, ORGANISATION.ORG_ID) = 
upper(p_username)
AND upper(Student.STUDENT_PASSWORD, ADMIN.ADMIN_PASSWORD, 
ORGANISATION.ORG_PASSWORD) = upper(p_password);
return (l_count > 0);
end;
```

above is authentication code i have made to get information from multiple tables and use them to authenticate a login. if i just do it for students it works fine but i need multiple types of user to be able to access the software and i cant make multiple authentication schemes run at the same time
all table name and column names are correct
below is the error i get
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7: PL/SQL: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: That SQL is terrifying. You're clearly not hashing passwords; you could authenticate someone based on another person's password; and there joins, so this will not scale well. Please research this more. Check out the custom authentication example in the Oracle APEX documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrong syntax. Try

```
select count(*) 
into l_count
from student,
     admin,
     organisation
where upper(p_username) in (upper(student.student_id),
                            upper(admin.admin_id),
                            upper(organisation.org_id)
                           )
  and upper(p_password) in (upper(student.student_password),
                            upper(admin.admin_password),
                            upper(organisation.org_password)
                           );
```

Comment: I cannot endorse this as an appropriate answer for a student of SQL at any level.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to try break this down, and work the problem through. There are a number of things to address.

#### Logic

How are you going to control uniqueness across the tables? There might be an ALBERT in both students *and* administration. It might even be the same person, a student and employee of the facility. I've been such a person.

#### Suggested SQL

There are no joins between your tables, this would turn the result into a cartesion product, and I'm pretty sure you could return true to ALBERT logging in with NIKOLA's password.

I think you probably meant to use a set operator

```
select ...
from student 
where ...
union all
select ...
from admin
where ...
```

The UNION *ALL* means there is no need to check for uniqueness, no need for an [extra sort](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2009/07/union-all-performance-accuracy.html).

#### Password protection

To be able to UPPER a password means you're storing it clear text. People today should inherit enough digital fluency that passwords **should not** be stored clear text. Ever.

See this article for an example of how to set up custom authentication in APEX by hashing passwords. A rare one amongst a disappointing number that did not hash passwords. This one also hashes with the username and some salt, which is better.
http://barrybrierley.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/custom-authentication-in-apex.html

It also starts to cover your needs regarding user type.

I'm sure there was an example in the APEX documentation, but I couldn't find it.

### User Type - Authorisation

Once you have established you have a valid user, you can determine what type of user they are, then control their access to various components using [Authorization Schemes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMDB/providing-security-through-authorization.htm#HTMDB12004).

For a more flexible system, I would abstract this further and use authorisation schemes to control *privileges* to certain components, and allocate these to *business roles*, which are in turn granted to *users*.

This serves your "multiple types of people".

### 'Record Exists' check

From early on I learned something at AskTom regarding checking for existence of rows, which seems to hold up well across all versions

```
declare
  ln_exists pls_integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  into ln_exists
  from dual
  where exists (
     select null 
     from your_table -- whatever you're looking for
     where id = p_id
  );
  return ln_exists = 1; -- true if exists
 end;
```

Oracle knows just how to spend the least effort in solving this problem.

Many other variations just select too many rows from the database.

### Shared applications

You *can* actually define multiple entry points using different authentication to the same application.
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2014/04/shared-authentication-across-multiple-apex-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

```
With valid_student as (
select count(*) as student_result 
from student 
where upper (p_username) = upper(student_id)
And upper(p_password) = upper(student_password)
),
valid_Admin as (
select count(*) as admin_result 
from admin
where upper (p_username) = upper(admin_id)
And upper(p_password) = upper(admin_password)
),
valid_org as (
select count(*) as org_result 
from organisation 
where upper (p_username) = upper(org_id)
And upper(p_password) = upper(org_password)
)
Select “Valid” as access_allowed
From valid_student s, valid_admin a, valid_org o
 Where s.student_result = 1 or a.admin_result = 1 or o.org_result = 1
```

Comment: This will ensure that the user name/ password combination is tested. I would prefer to use a packaged function to handle the validation. Also, this reads as though your passwords are passed in an unencrypted state!